# .hex/s-rec format converter to elf

Tags: microcontroller, elf, converters, format-conversion

Does someone know of a converter from [Intel .hex file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX) or [Motorola S-record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SREC_(file_format)) to elf file format?

Comment: The conversion is usually in the opposite direction since converting ELF to one of the primitive bootloader formats discards information such as which section is code as opposed to data, etc. Can you give more information on what your circumstance is?

Comment: S19/HEX files contain just the loadable image.  ELF contains extra information (used for mapping, etc.)  I suppose you could convert to ELF leaving the other information `blank` while conforming to the overall format of the file but I don't see the reason.  Do you have a tool (e.g., simulator/debugger) that can load only ELF and nothing else?  Still, without the extra information it won't be much help.

Comment: The reason for the conversion is security research, most of the tools don't support those formats, but they support `elf` format.

Comment: objcopy will do it but it always takes me a while to figure it out.  or you can just do it yourself all three of these file formats are pretty simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
objcopy.exe -I ihex -O elf32-little "input.hex" "output.hex.elf"
```

did the trick.